# Xcode12; New “Subclass MPMediaItem must implement -valueForProperty” error

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14, mpmediaitem, xcode12

Just updated to Xcode 12.0 from the last version of Xcode 11/iOS13 and am getting an error in AppDelegate: `Thread 1: "Subclass MPMediaItem must implement -valueForProperty: defined in [MPMediaItem class]."`

When the app starts, I MPMediaQuery the library for songs and store them to a @Published variable in an Observable Object like this:

```
@Published var songs = [MPMediaItem]()


init() {
  self.songs = MPMediaQuery.songs().items
}
```

Later when I want to access a property I do so like this:

```
Text(self.observableObject.songs[0].title)
```

I’ve tried changing these to use `.value(forProperty: "MPMediaItemPropertyTitle")` but it doesn’t feel to be use a string over a property (and Xcode then pops up errors like `Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report apple.`) AFAIK, I’m not subclassing MPMediaItem anywhere and I’ve tried Googling the error above with no luck.

Anyone know what’s going on?

Comment: Did anyone find solution for this issue ?.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is useful to your situation, but I recently came across a simiar problem.

In my case I needed to change 2 things that triggered this crash:

1. I was initialising an empty `MPMediaItem()` as placeholder when no current song was loaded. The crash happened when trying to access a property (e.g. `title`) on this empty instance. Upon removing the empty `MPMediaItem()` and implementing a different placeholder approach, the problem went away.
2. To test music on the simlator I was using a `DummyMediaQuery: MPMediaQuery` which returned an array of `DummyMediaItem: MPMediaItem`. In the `DummyMediaItem` class I did:

```
final class DummyMediaItem: MPMediaItem {
    private let _artist: String
    override var artist: String { return _artist }

    private let _title: String
    override var title: String { return _title }

    // and so on...

    // fix: crash in iOS 14
    override func value(forProperty property: String) -> Any? {
        return nil
    }
}
```